# How to put Admob on a Nativescript PlaceHolder View

Tags: admob, nativescript

There is a very good [Admob plugin to Nativescript](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-admob). With it we can create banners on the very top and bottom Page. It is possible to customize the margin too.

But I have tried to use this plugin on a [placeholder-view](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/placeholder) like the edited image below. I had no success. Is there some way to do that.

[image]

```
   var admob = require("nativescript-admob");

   admob.createBanner({
      // NEED TO PUT THE VIEW HERE, but it is not working
      view: "????",
      testing: true, // set to false to get real banners
      size: admob.AD_SIZE.BANNER,
      androidBannerId: "ca-app-pub-AAAAAAAA/BBBBBBB",
      margins: {
        bottom: 50
      }
    })
```

So, how to create an Nativescript placeholder, and how to implement it on the admob function code.

Comment: Please share code you have written so far, also please share logs for any errors that prevent your app to work

Comment: On docks from Admob NativeScript says that if you inform the view on the object that call admob creation, it will be placed on that page. I updated the question to show how it would be.

Comment: Currently it is not possible using nativescipt admob plugin. You can you examples given on https://www.nativescript.org/blog/monetize-your-nativescript-apps-with-admob-(part-1---ios) and https://www.nativescript.org/blog/monetize-your-nativescript-apps-with-admob-(part-2---android) to replace placeholder with the AdView.

Comment: found any solution?